# React Native Table Cell filling whole row instead of just cell

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a table in react native but the cells is filling the whole row space instead of just the cell. Why?

```
import { Table, TableWrapper, Row, Cell } from 'react-native-table-component';
...

this.state = {
      tenantData: {},
      tenantLedger: [],
      tableHead: ['Date of Credit', 'Description', 'Charge', 'Credit', 'Balance'],
      widthArr: [80, 95, 65, 65, 65]
};
...

<Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#C1C0B9'}}>
   <Row
      data={this.state.tableHead}
      style={styles.head}
      textStyle={styles.text}
      widthArr={this.state.widthArr}
   />
   {
      tableData.map((rowData, index) => (
         <TableWrapper key={index} style={styles.row}>
            {
               rowData.map((cellData, cellIndex) => (
                  <Cell key={cellIndex} data={cellData} textStyle={styles.text} />
               ))
            }
         </TableWrapper>
      ))
   }
</Table>
...

text: { textAlign: 'center', fontWeight: '100' },
row: { height: 40, backgroundColor: '#E7E6E1' },
head: { height: 40, backgroundColor: '#f1f8ff' },
```

My output is:
[image]

Does anyone know why the cells are not in the correct position?

Thanks

Comment: Try setting `flex-direction: 'row'` in `styles.row`

Comment: It almost fix the issue. The only problem is that the columns are not aligned to the head columns.

Comment: Trying setting `widthArr` on `TableWrapper`, and if that does not work, then you can set the `width` on each `Cell` using the `widthArr` and `cellIndex`

Answer (score -1):

You do not need "TableWrapper" and "Cell" to show data . "Cell" will have full width . if you just want to show data

**Replace this**

```
{
      tableData.map((rowData, index) => (
         <TableWrapper key={index} style={styles.row}>
            {
               rowData.map((cellData, cellIndex) => (
                  <Cell key={cellIndex} data={cellData} textStyle={styles.text} />
               ))
            }
         </TableWrapper>
      ))
   }
```

**With**

```
<Rows data={state.rowData} textStyle={styles.text}/>
```

**Note : import "Rows" from 'react-native-table-component';**

Comment: I would like to have touchableopacity for a specific Cell